# How to access GitHub Actions Environment Secrets locally and remotely

Tags: python, environment-variables, github-actions

On my local repository, I have a .gitignore'd `config.py` file that holds sensitive tokens. On the remote repo, I grab the GitHub Secrets using Python's `os`.

Here is the relevant snippet of my code, is this the best practice for it to work both locally and remotely?

```py
import os

try: # This should run locally
    import config
    ACCESS_TOKEN = config.ACCESS_TOKEN
    OWNER_ID = config.OWNER_ID
except: # This should run on GitHub Actions
    ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN']
    OWNER_ID = os.environ['OWNER_ID']
```

Here is the full code: https://github.com/Andrew6rant/Andrew6rant/blob/main/today.py

Comment: Yes, this is great. Alternatively, you can set environment variables in your local environment, then `os.environ` works for both situations.

Comment: Why not something like https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ (or any other way to set env vars locally) so you don't have to conditionally handle it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve it, but personally I did this:

1. Use config values always in Python - don't handle environment anywhere.
2. Overwrite values in the config file on GitHub Action before executing Python from GitHub secrets - separate step independent from Python.
3. For local development we keep config file in 1password vault and not keeping it in GitHub to avoid leaking secrets and vurnable data.

In my case I keep config in JSON format, but you can pick any.